# Signs of products of permutations with given values sums

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There is a funny property of permutations, which is valid for $n=2,3,4$, but it would be interesting to know if it is a general fact.

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ be three permutations of numbers $[1,\ldots,n]$ satisfying the following property
$ i + \sigma_1(i) = \sigma_2(i) + \sigma_3(i)$
for all $i\in [1,\ldots,n]$.

Is it true that $sgn(\sigma_1) = sgn(\sigma_2)sgn(\sigma_3)$, where $sgn$ stands for the sign of the permutation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which addition are we using?

Comment: @JonathanY. Presumably addition of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a computer search shown that it is false.

A counterexample is the following triple: ((2,3,4,5,1),(1,4,2,5,3),(2,1,5,4,3)).

But It is interesting, that triples of permutations with the same values sums which contradict the property are very rare guests.